# Windows IoT and DS3231 RTC clock

Tags: arduino, i2c, windowsiot

For my project I need the current time & date. Unfortunately the RP2 loses everything when it's turned off. The next thing is, that I won't have an internet connection to use NTP. 
For this reasing I need to implement a DS3231 RTC module. 
The communication of all devices runs over I2C (Raspberry <-> Arduino <-> DS3231). 
At the moment my Arduino communicates with the module and stores the date and time in char-arrays. The RP2 communicates with the Arduino to get the date/time. That actually works pretty good. But I'd like to communicate directly with the module to save ressources on the Arduino (it's only a Nano). 
So therefore I'd like to know if someone has experiences with the module and Windows IoT.

Below you'll find my current solution:

Arduino:

```
#include "Wire.h"
#define DS3231_I2C_ADDRESS 0x68
#define MyAddress 0x40   /* Define the i2c address */

char time_char[10];
char date_char[10];

byte ReceivedData;

// Convert binary coded decimal to normal decimal numbers
byte bcdToDec(byte val)
{
  return( (val/16*10) + (val%16) );
}

void setup()
{
  Wire.begin(MyAddress);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.onReceive(I2CReceived);
  Wire.onRequest(I2CRequest);
}

void readDS3231time(byte *second, byte *minute, byte *hour, byte *dayOfWeek, byte *dayOfMonth, byte *month, byte *year)
{
  Wire.beginTransmission(DS3231_I2C_ADDRESS);
  Wire.write(0); // set DS3231 register pointer to 00h
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.requestFrom(DS3231_I2C_ADDRESS, 7);
  // request seven bytes of data from DS3231 starting from register 00h

  *second = bcdToDec(Wire.read() & 0x7f);
  *minute = bcdToDec(Wire.read());
  *hour = bcdToDec(Wire.read() & 0x3f);
  *dayOfWeek = bcdToDec(Wire.read());
  *dayOfMonth = bcdToDec(Wire.read());
  *month = bcdToDec(Wire.read());
  *year = bcdToDec(Wire.read());
}

void displayTime()
{
  String hour_str, minute_str, second_str, day_str, month_str, year_str, hour_str_orig, minute_str_orig, second_str_orig, time_str, date_str;
  byte second, minute, hour, dayOfWeek, dayOfMonth, month, year;
  // retrieve data from DS3231
  readDS3231time(&second, &minute, &hour, &dayOfWeek, &dayOfMonth, &month,&year);

  if (hour<10)
  {
    hour_str_orig = (hour);
    hour_str = ("0" + hour_str_orig);
  }
  else
  {
    hour_str = (hour);
  }

  if (minute<10)
  {
   minute_str_orig = (minute);
   minute_str = ("0" + minute_str_orig);
  }
  else
  {
   minute_str = (minute);
  }

  if (second<10)
  {
   second_str_orig = (second);
   second_str = ("0" + second_str_orig);
  }
  else
  {
   second_str = (second);
  }

  day_str = (dayOfMonth);
  month_str = (month);
  year_str = (year);

  time_str = (hour_str + ":" + minute_str + ":" + second_str);
  date_str = (day_str + "." + month_str + "." + "20" +year_str);


  time_str.toCharArray(time_char, 10); 
  date_str.toCharArray(date_char, 10);       

}
void loop()
{
  displayTime(); // send the real-time clock data to IoT
  delay(1000); // every second
}

void I2CReceived(int NumberOfBytes)
{
    /* WinIoT have sent data byte; read it */
    ReceivedData = Wire.read();
}

void I2CRequest()
  {

if (ReceivedData == 50)    
{
    Wire.write(time_char);
}

if (ReceivedData == 51) 
{
    Wire.write(date_char);
}

}
```

IoT:

```
public async void TestFunction()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        for (byte DataToBeSend = 50; DataToBeSend < 52; DataToBeSend++)
        {
            if (DataToBeSend == 50)
            {
                byte ReceivedData;

                ReceivedData = await Time.WriteRead_OneByte(DataToBeSend);

                await Task.Delay(10);
            }

            if (DataToBeSend == 51)
            {
                byte ReceivedData;

                ReceivedData = await Time.WriteRead_OneByte(DataToBeSend);

                await Task.Delay(10);
            }
        }

        await Task.Delay(1000);

    }
}
```

Class:

```
  public class Time
    {
        private static string AQS;
        private static DeviceInformationCollection DIS;
        public static float result_fl;


        public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<byte> WriteRead_OneByte(byte ByteToBeSend)
        {
            byte[] ReceivedData = new byte[10];


            /* Gateway's I2C SLAVE address */
            int SlaveAddress = 64;              // 0x40

            try
            {
                // Initialize I2C
                var Settings = new I2cConnectionSettings(SlaveAddress);
                Settings.BusSpeed = I2cBusSpeed.StandardMode;

                if (AQS == null || DIS == null)
                {
                    AQS = I2cDevice.GetDeviceSelector("I2C1");
                    DIS = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(AQS);
                }


                using (I2cDevice Device = await I2cDevice.FromIdAsync(DIS[0].Id, Settings))
                {
                    /* Send byte to Arduino Nano */
                    Device.Write(new byte[] { ByteToBeSend });

                    /* Read byte from Arduino Nano */
                    Device.Read(ReceivedData);

                    /* Rewrite Array to avoid empty space in source array */
                    var i = ReceivedData.Length - 1;
                    while (ReceivedData[i] == 255)
                    {
                        --i;
                    }

                    var date_time_arr = new byte[i + 1];
                    Array.Copy(ReceivedData, date_time_arr, i + 1);

                    /* Show date or time */
                    string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(date_time_arr);
                    Debug.WriteLine(result);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
            return ReceivedData[0];
        }
    }
```

Tell me if you need more information. 
Thanks!

Comment: Do you get any clock information in the IOT?

Comment: @BlurrySterk sorry for my belated reply. Yes I get the clock information but only over the way through the Arduino

Comment: I cannot detremine what your issue actually is. I would implement the I2C communication directly in your IoT. Have you tried it there?

Comment: And that's exactly the point where I stuck. I'm unable to translate the arduino code into c# for IoT correctly. When I try to implement it into IoT I receive nonsense or nothing at all...

Comment: Does the code above include your effort?

Comment: 50/50 - the parts "void readDS3231time" in the Arduino as well as parts of the "class" (the connection) are not mine. I understand what they're doing but I'm missing some kind of a wire.h-lib for IoT. For example, how can I tell the DS3231 to send me 7 bytes without the requestFrom function?

Comment: My recommendation in that regard is to study the actual Wire.h and Wire.c(pp) library to see what they did.

Comment: What I meant is; did you include above the code where you tried to interface with the RTC directly from the IoT?

Comment: Not yet. I'll publish it later in the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the belated reply! 
My solution so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;
using Windows.Devices.I2c;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace _015_Test15_I2C_Clock_RTC3231
{
    public class I2C_Time
    {
        private static string AQS;
        private static DeviceInformationCollection DIS;

        public static async Task GetTimeFromDS3231()
        {

            /* DS3231 I2C SLAVE address */
            int SlaveAddress = 0x68;

            try
            {
                // Initialize I2C
                var Settings = new I2cConnectionSettings(SlaveAddress);
                Settings.BusSpeed = I2cBusSpeed.StandardMode;

                if (AQS == null || DIS == null)
                {
                    AQS = I2cDevice.GetDeviceSelector("I2C1");
                    DIS = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(AQS);
                }


                using (I2cDevice Device = await I2cDevice.FromIdAsync(DIS[0].Id, Settings))
                {
                    byte[] writeBuf = { 0x00 };
                    Device.Write(writeBuf);
                    byte[] readBuf = new byte[7];
                    Device.Read(readBuf);
                    byte second = bcdToDec((byte)(readBuf[0] & 0x7f));
                    byte minute = bcdToDec(readBuf[1]);
                    byte hour = bcdToDec((byte)(readBuf[2] & 0x3f));
                    byte dayOfWeek = bcdToDec(readBuf[3]);
                    byte dayOfMonth = bcdToDec(readBuf[4]);
                    byte month = bcdToDec(readBuf[5]);
                    byte year = bcdToDec(readBuf[6]);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Error in I2C_Time Class");
            }
        }

        private static byte bcdToDec(byte val)
            {
                return (byte)(((int)val / 16 * 10) + ((int)val % 16));
            }
        }
    }
```

To set the clock:

```
 using (I2cDevice Device = await I2cDevice.FromIdAsync(DIS[0].Id, Settings))
            {
                byte write_seconds = decToBcd(set_Time_now_seconds);
                byte write_minutes = decToBcd(set_Time_now_minutes);
                byte write_hours = decToBcd(set_Time_now_hours);
                byte write_dayofweek = decToBcd(set_Date_now_dayofweek);
                byte write_day = decToBcd(set_Date_now_day);
                byte write_month = decToBcd(set_Date_now_month);
                byte write_year = decToBcd(set_Date_now_year);

                byte[] write_time = {0x00, write_seconds, write_minutes, write_hours, write_dayofweek, write_day, write_month, write_year };

                Device.Write(write_time);

            }
        // Convert normal decimal numbers to binary coded decimal
    private static byte decToBcd(byte val)
    {
        return (byte)(((int)val / 10 * 16) + ((int)val % 10));
    }
```