# Windows IoT Raspberry Pi 3 C# RTC DS3231

Tags: c#, uwp, raspberry-pi3, windows-iot-core-10, real-time-clock

this post may seems duplicate as [Windows IoT and DS3231 RTC clock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34964682/windows-iot-and-ds3231-rtc-clock)
 but it doesn't seem to work for me. i don't have experience using i2c in this environment.

My intended functionality is,

1. at startup check if there is any network connectivity to update system clock
2. if offline the system will read `datetime` from `DS3231` and update
   the system `datetime`
3. any changes of `datetime` from `datepicker` or
   `timepicker` it will update `DS3231`

My problem is

1. How to check for network availibility to update system clock.
2. to read from `DS3231`
   using `i1cdevice.writeread` requires to `write` `read address` separately? 
   does the `i2c` automatically reads all the data until `stop` bit is received or i have to setup a counter ?

   ```
   private const byte DS3231_I2C_WADDR = 0xD0;
   private const byte DS3231_I2C_RADDR = 0xD1;
   private I2cDevice DS3231_RTC; 

   byte[] i2CWriteBuffer;
   byte[] i2CReadBuffer;

   private async void Read_DS3231_RTC()
   {
       var settings = new I2cConnectionSettings(DS3231_I2C_RADDR);
       settings.BusSpeed = I2cBusSpeed.StandardMode;
       var controller = await I2cController.GetDefaultAsync();
       DS3231_RTC = controller.GetDevice(settings);

       try
       {
           DS3231_RTC.WriteRead(new byte[] { DS3231_I2C_RADDR }, i2CReadBuffer);
           }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           StatusMessage.Text = "Fail to Init I2C:" + e.Message;
           return;
       }
   }
   ```
3. to write to `DS3231`
   there are `dateicker` & `timepicker` for time setting
   upon setting the `datetime` how could I update to `DS3231`

   ```
   private void DatePicker_DateChanged(object sender, DatePickerValueChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       DateTimeSettings.SetSystemDateTime(e.NewDate.UtcDateTime);
       SetTime_DS3231();
   }

   private void TimePicker_TimeChanged(object sender, TimePickerValueChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       var currentDate = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();

       var newDateTime = new DateTime(currentDate.Year,
                                      currentDate.Month,
                                      currentDate.Day,
                                      e.NewTime.Hours,
                                      e.NewTime.Minutes,
                                      e.NewTime.Seconds);

       DateTimeSettings.SetSystemDateTime(newDateTime);
   }
   ```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.How to check for network availibility to update system clock.

You can use GetIsNetworkAvailable method of NetworkInterface class to check whether internet connected or not. You can get more knowleage about how to check internet connectivity type in Universal Windows Platform from this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35901526/how-to-check-internet-connectivity-type-in-universal-windows-platform)
.

```
bool isInternetConnected = NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
```

> 2.to read from DS3231 using i1cdevice.writeread requires to write read address separately? does the i2c automatically reads all the data
>   until stop bit is received or i have to setup a counter ?

It is not necessary to separate write read. [WriteRead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.i2c.i2cdevice#Windows_Devices_I2c_I2cDevice_WriteRead_System_Byte___System_Byte___) method Performs an atomic operation to write data to and then read data from the inter-integrated circuit (I2 C) bus on which the device is connected, and sends a restart condition between the write and read operations. The second parameter is the buffer to which you want to read the data from the I2 C bus. The length of the buffer determines how much data to request from the device.It does not stop automatically until stop bit is received.If the I2 C device negatively acknowledged the data transfer before the entire buffer was read, there will be error(Error Code 0x8007045D).

> 3.to write to DS3231 there are dateicker & timepicker for time setting upon setting the datetime how could I update to DS3231

As TRS replied in the topic [Windows IoT and DS3231 RTC clock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34964682/windows-iot-and-ds3231-rtc-clock)
, he/she provided the method to set clock.

**New Update:**

```
    private async void SetTime_DS3231(DateTime dt)
    {
        int SlaveAddress = 0x68;

        try
        {
            // Initialize I2C
            var Settings = new I2cConnectionSettings(SlaveAddress);
            Settings.BusSpeed = I2cBusSpeed.StandardMode;

            if (AQS == null || DIS == null)
            {
                AQS = I2cDevice.GetDeviceSelector("I2C1");
                DIS = await Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(AQS);
            }

            using (I2cDevice Device = await I2cDevice.FromIdAsync(DIS[0].Id, Settings))
            {
                byte write_seconds = decToBcd((byte)dt.Second);
                byte write_minutes = decToBcd((byte)dt.Minute);
                byte write_hours = decToBcd((byte)dt.Hour);
                byte write_dayofweek = decToBcd((byte)dt.DayOfWeek);
                byte write_day = decToBcd((byte)dt.Day);
                byte write_month = decToBcd((byte)dt.Month);
                byte write_year = decToBcd((byte)(dt.Year%100));

                byte[] write_time = { 0x00, write_seconds, write_minutes, write_hours, write_dayofweek, write_day, write_month, write_year };

                Device.Write(write_time);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private static byte decToBcd(byte val)
    {
        return (byte)(((int)val / 10 * 16) + ((int)val % 10));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. for `Write` how to I apply the method as it's `using (I2cDevice Device = await I2cDevice.FromIdAsync(DIS[0].Id, Settings))`

Comment: I have additional issue is that when I insert `SetTime_DS3231(newDateTime)` at the end of  `TimePicker_TimeChanged` and `SetTime_DS3231(e.NewDate.UtcDateTime)` at the end of  `DatePicker_DateChanged` and I encountered `System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access is denied. (Excep_FromHResult 0x80070005)'`

Comment: You need to add System Management capability in your Package.appxmanifest since DateTimeSettings.SetSystemDateTime need the permission.

Comment: If ` if( isInternetConnected == true)` & the system clock will be updated via IoT, how do i know that when the `time` has been updated, so that i can update `DS3231` once the system time is update over the network.

Comment: By default, IoT Core devices are setup to synchronize time from time.windows.com on boot. You need to use a NTP service to sync the date/time manually.

Comment: Oh.. in that case.. I check for internet connectivity before reading from the RTC? If there is internet connectivity.. I will skip reading from RTC.. I also realize that is there any class to notify that the datetime have been synced with time.windows.com..

Comment: It seems that there is no any class to notify that the datetime has been synced with NTP.

Comment: during `decToBcd` conversion for `Year` i noticed that `(byte)dt.Year` = 226 where `dt.Year` = 2018 .. after conversion `write_year` = 51 and is written to `DS3231` ... when I read it back I get 66 for `year` ...  is there something i did wrong? I pass `DateTime.Now` in `TimePicker_TimeChanged`
 to `SetTime_DS3231(DateTime.Now);`

Comment: I have updated the code,please refer to the new updated code.I think it is due to the max value of byte is 255. Since i have no one piece of DS3231, i can not verify the code.If it works or not,please let me know.

Comment: Hi.. it didn't work.. but i manage to get it to work.. code as follow; `byte write_year = decToBcd(dt.Year % 100);` `return (byte)((val % 10) | (val / 10) << 0x4);` ...

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code.I have updated my reply according with your code so that it will be helpful for somebody else.